# Every nonzero linear transformation from $\mathbb R^n$ to itself has at least one nonzero eigenvalue. Is my counter example valid?

Tags: linear-algebra

Technically, could I use a matrix that is a $2\times2$ upper triangular matrix? It's eigenvalue is 0, but I'm unsure if it could be classified as a non zero linear transformation.

Comment: It is a non-zero linear transformation  if the first row second column element is not zero.

Comment: You can use a rotation matrix in $\Bbb R^2$ for example. $\Bbb R$ isn't algebraically closed, so...

Comment: Unless every entry of the matrix is $0$, it's a non-zero transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it and its $n\times n$ counterpart are fine counterexamples (for $n\ge1$, of course, since for $n=0$ or $n=1$ there are no counterexamples).